# I want sql / Teradata query for below R-code Any help appreciated

Tags: sql, teradata

I want write sql/ Teradata query for below R-code. I attached R code for your refrence.

```
SELECT `ID`, `Date`, `Agent`, `group`
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY `ID`, `group`, `Agent` ORDER BY `Date`) AS `q01`
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      CEIL(CAST(difftime(`Date`, MIN(`Date`) OVER (PARTITION BY `ID`), 'week' AS `units`) / 4.0 AS INTEGER)) AS `group`
    FROM (
      SELECT `ID`, CAST(`Date` AS DATE) AS `Date`, `Agent`
      FROM `dbplyr_003`
    )
  )
)
WHERE (`q01` <= 1)
Thanks
```

Comment: that is already SQL.  have you tried running it in Teradata?  what happens?  you will probalby have to change the quote characters from backtick to double-quotes

Comment: Correct, Teradata doesn't play nice with backticks.  By the way, using reserved words as column names is a pretty bad idea.